# Gravitational attraction between two objects of non-uniform mass-density

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

Is there a formula to calculate the gravitational force of attraction between two bodies - both are suspended in 3D, both have a non-uniform mass density, both are closed geometric shapes in 3D, and cannot be deformed.

[I'm a computer engineer, and something at work requires this]

Comment: I suggest that you first do a rough calculation, assuming that the bodies are uniform spheres, to get a ballpark estimate of the force.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The force on object $1$ due to object $2$ can be computed by doing a six-dimensional integral,

$$-G\int_{V_1}d^3\mathbf{r}_1\rho_1(\mathbf{r}_1)\int_{V_2}d^3\mathbf{r}_2\rho_2(\mathbf{r}_2)\frac{\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2}{|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|^3},$$

where $\rho_1(\mathbf{r}_1)$ is the mass density of object $1$ and $\rho_2(\mathbf{r}_2)$ that of object $2$.

This is the continuum form of the discrete-mass formula

$$-\sum_{i\in V_1}\sum_{j\in V_2}\frac{Gm_im_j(\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j)}{|\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j|^3}$$

which just sums up the forces between each chunk of mass in the first object and each chunk of mass in the second object.